# synonym to acquiescently: "agree but not really want to" adverb

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I believe I recall there is an adverb that means "do something but not really want to" specifically I think meaning is more like that it is it's NOT really CONSENSUAL but one sort of agrees anyway to appease the other. It would be a synonym to something like "acquiescently".

I forget the word and google seems to be of no help. The word is not reluctantly. Thanks so much :)

Comment: 'Reluctantly' fits the bill. Asking for 'words one has forgotten' from among a choice of synonyms is off-topic. And a simple search for synonyms of 'reluctantly' is obviously indicated.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is **begrudgingly**. *Merriam-Webster* defines **begrudging** thus:

> said, done, or given reluctantly : GRUDGING

*begrudging acceptance/admiration/respect*

Comment: I've heard the word begrudgingly many times and in the context that I've heard it it's often implied that there's some level of visible sign of bitterness toward the decision to go along with the action. I know Merriam-Webster doesn't explicitly say this but I think you will find this to be the case when you read or hear the word. Merriam-Webster does explicitly describe begrudgingly as reluctant.

acquiescently on the other hand stresses "without protest", "passively", and "in a docile manner" in it's definitions. This contrasts my understanding of begrudgingly.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure the word ***[acquiescently](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/acquiescently/synonyms)*** is the best of clues you are giving

I can think of ***yieldingly*** or [***in spite of oneself***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20spite%20of%20oneself).

You can also try and find your word in the synonyms of [***reticently***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/reticently.html) (which is not bad for the meaning you are looking for.